# require vs. package-initialize?

Tags: init-file, package, start-up, require

Ok, this is a noob question but I've digging into this enough that I think it's reasonable to ask :)

My question: In one's .emacs / init.el file, can one use `require` to load packages that were installed via the emacs package manager?  If so, how?

I've seen a lot of code that says `(require 'package-name)`, where 'package-name is something like `'powerline` or `'rainbow-delimiters`.  The docs say that `require` basically tries to `load` the file, making sure not to load it twice.  `load` works by looking in all the dirs in the `load-path` variable.  This makes sense.

`package-initialize` goes through the list of installed packages and tries to run their auto-loads (and possibly defer further work) so that all the packages I've previously installed will work.  This makes sense.

My confusion comes from my init.el: even though I've got packages installed (I can both see the packages in the filesystem and everything works great if I run `(package-initialize)`) using `require` doesn't work.  Emacs complains that use-package isn't in `load-path` and I can confirm that if I don't call `(package-initialize)` that the `load-path` doesn't ilst ~/.emacs.d/elpa (or anything under it).

My question: In one's .emacs / init.el file, can one use `require` to load packages that were installed via the emacs package manager?  If so, how?
Do I need to manually add the directory to `load-path`?  Should this normally work and I probably broke something with my personal init.el?

Any help would be appreciated - I'm clearly not getting something about how `require` works (and many other things too, I'm sure :)  )

**EDIT**: My version: GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2018-05-30

Also, I'm playing around with `use-package` and am running into the same problem - if I add the directory containing `use-package` to load path *without* running `(package-initialize)` first then `use-package` fails because it wants to use the package `bind-key`. `bind-key` is installed but not listed in `load-path` so emacs barfs at that point.

Comment: For this question, Emacs version is very important. There are significant changes between Emacs 25, 26 and 27 (the development series). Mention the Emacs version you need this answer for.

Comment: Please start `emacs -Q`, run `M-x package-initialize`, and check `load-path` again. I have a similar system. After executing above steps I have many `load-path` entries with `elpa` in them. The option `-Q` essentially avoids loading the initialization files of the system and the user.

Comment: @Tobias - I think my goal is the opposite of this - I'm wondering how to avoid doing `package-initialize` and yet still run my `init.el`.  My understanding is that `use-package` can then lazy-load packages as I need them, thus reducing 'boot' times *and* giving me a snazzy, nice syntax for loading packages.

Comment: It is for error analysis not for permanent usage.

Comment: Sure - sorry!  when `emacs -Q` starts up `load-path` doesn't have any paths to my `elpa` dir.  After I run `(package-initialize)` then `load-path` does have a bunch of `elpa` directories.  Is that what you were looking for? (I don't understand what this tells you?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use `require`, yes, but *only after* running `package-initialize` (in Emacs≥27, this is done for you before the beginning of the `.emacs` file).

Note that for 99% of the packages `require` should not be needed (the autoloads should cause the package to be loaded as soon as you try to make use of it).  E.g. if you have `use-package` installed as an ELPA package, then you should be able to use `(use-package ...)` without first doing `(require 'use-package)`.

But again, that's only true *after* having run `package-initialize`.

Comment: Did you mean Emacs≥27?

Comment: Can I ask what the point of `'require` is?  (Is it left over from an era when it was useful?)

Comment: At this point, does that mean that `(use-package)` is mostly useful for configuring and auto-installing a given package?  Other than the auto-installing and the nice syntax, what does `use-package` provide?  (the web page for use-package talks a lot about lazy-loading packages - how can that happen if `package-initialize` has already loaded everything?

Comment: @MikeTheTall `require` is still very much used and useful - it's the canonical way to load libraries. What Stefan is saying is that most user configuration code seldom needs to eagerly load library code.

Comment: @MikeTheTall `package-initialize` does not eagerly load installed packages - it only adds their directories to `load-path` and evaluates their [autoloads](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Libraries.html).

Comment: @MikeTheTall `use-package` is just a handy syntax for keeping various settings related to a single package grouped together and making it easier, especially for beginner Emacsites, to lazy-load packages by default. Ultimately, everything `use-package` can do, vanilla Emacs gives you ways of doing more flexibly, but many find `use-package` more convenient or more aesthetically pleasing.