# How to autoload a non-elpa package such as help-fns+.el?

Tags: init-file, help, autoload, help-mode

I read from some posts ([require vs. package-initialize?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/44266), and [here](https://a-nickels-worth.blogspot.com/2007/11/effective-emacs.html)) that Emacs can autoload packages installed via ELPA/MELPA, which avoids using `require` on packages and speeds up loading during initialization. And quoting [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/44287):

> Note that for 99% of the packages require should not be needed (the
> autoloads should cause the package to be loaded as soon as you try to
> make use of it).

I do have quite a few usages of `(require ...)` in my `init.el` that significantly slow down emacs initialization. By turning things on and off, some culprits seems to be

```
(require 'help-fns+)   ; about 0.2 to 0.3 s
(require 'org)
(require 'ob-octave)   ; not sure, but up to 1 s
```

I tried to just comment out these `require` statements (since I use emacs 27.1 under Ubuntu). But [help-fns+.el](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/help-fns+.el) does not seem to work anymore. Functions defined there (e.g. `describe-buffer`) can no longer be found.

My questions are:

*Is it the right way to take advantage of autoloads by just removing the `require` call? Or is it because `help-fns+.el` doesn't have the autoload capability from ELPA?*

*If the latter case, (how) can I autoload `help-fns+.el` and avoid a hard `require` in `init.el`?*

Comment: Do `C-h i g (elisp)Autoload` - ELPA packages may be using it, but it has nothing to do with ELPA per se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some alternatives.  Do any of them after putting the library in a directory that's in your `load-path`.

1. Unconditionally load the library.

   ```
   (require 'help-fns+)
   ```
2. Autoload the library for individual commands (or other functions, but typically commands), by putting a sexp like this in your init file:

   ```
   (autoload 'describe-command "help-fns+" "Help commands." t)
   ```

   Then, whenever you invoke that command, the file will automatically be loaded.
3. But library [help-fns+.el](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el) also provides `;;;###autoload` cookies, so you can alternatively generate a file of autoloads for it, using command `update-file-autoloads`.

As @NickD wrote in a comment, see the Elisp manual, node [Autoload](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Autoload.html).